# Fallback to default TYPO3 page type if invalid type number/typeNum is requested

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

In my *TYPO3 9 LTS* installation, when a request with an invalid (i.e. no TypoScript-configured) type number (`PAGE.typeNum`) comes in, my installation returns an ugly error message:

Example request: https://www.example.com?type=1234

Example response:

```
Service Unavailable (503)
The page is not configured! [type=1234][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=1234 configured.
More information regarding this error might be available online.
```

The *more information* link points to https://typo3.org/go/exception/CMS/1294587217 , but there currently isn't any helpful information how to better configure my installation.

These error messages are also annoying as they may be triggered by webcrawlers and each request creates an error entry in the TYPO system protocol.

What can I do to fallback to/serve the default `type=0` HTML page if a requested type number is not configured?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK TYPO3 can currently not properly handle that. A 503 is generated, but the according errorHandler in the site configuration is not triggered.

At least the error message will be a bit less ugly ("Ooops, an error...") when you are in TYPO3_CONTEXT=Production ...

There is a feature request to make the unknown page type behave like 404: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86844

For the time being I suggest adding redirects (301) for all types that you do not want to serve outside of TYPO3 (e.g. .htaccess RewriteRules or nginx rewrites).